# Dynamics365 - adding a new auto-number field to an existing entity and fill its values

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365, autonumber

I need to add a new "auto-number" field to an entity in Dynamics365 CE.

Thanks to Jonas Rapp's excellent XrmToolbox "Auto Number Manager", *adding* the field and defining its look is a breeze.

My challenge is: I have 100'000+ existing rows in that entity - how can I update the existing rows with the correct auto-numbering values?

I have tried it - but even if I make the "auto-number" field "required", creating it doesn't fill the values for the existing rows. I would have *hoped* this would be done automagically - as with a "computed column" or a new "not null" column with a default value n SQL Server.

Any easy ways of doing this? Can I somehow updates those existing rows via a workflow, or via the REST API ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can develop some ETL job using Scribe or SSIS + Kingswaysoft to fetch all the records in order you want and generate the sequenced Autonumber to update them back.

You can do with Power Automate flow as well.

Alternatively [Jonas trick](https://jonasr.app/2019/02/anm-existing/) should help you too.

Comment: Jonas to the rescue ! Thanks, Arun - check this post out and implemented it successfully in my situation